# MessageDefinitionSends REST API returns empty body with 404 error

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, postman

I'm new to Salesforce and I've been trying to use the messageDefinitionSends endpoint to send a single email message. I started by creating an email message, a data extension and a triggered send. I saved, published and started the triggered send.

Then, using Postman, I requested an access token via `https://myorgsubdomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token` and got the following:

```
{
    "access_token": "sometoken",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 1079,
    "scope": "email_read email_send email_write ...", (and others, removed for simplicity)
    "soap_instance_url": "https://myorgsubdomain.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/",
    "rest_instance_url": "https://myorgsubdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/"
}
```

Then, I copied the token and used in the following request

```
POST /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:123456/send HTTP/1.1
Host: myorgsubdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer sometoken

{
    "To": {
        "Address": "me@my.org",
        "SubscriberKey": "me@my.org"
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

where `123456` is the external key for the triggered send I created previously. The recipient SubscriberKey equals the destination email address for this specific case (I confirmed via the SOAP API). When I POST the request I receive an empty response body with the HTTP response 404. I've also tried using the endpoint `https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:123456/send` but I either receive a 404 or 401 response.

I'm struggling with this issue for a while now and I have no idea what might be wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I would verify the key/id of your Triggered Send Definition. The only time I receive a 404 is when this is incorrect.

Comment: @Gortonington I've checked the external key of the Triggered Send Definition countless times. I've even tried changing it a few times (I paused, edited, published and restarted the Definition) and the result is still the same. It matches the one I see in the column "External Key".

Comment: Is the token you are using associated with the same BU as your TSD? Sorry for the dumb questions, I just feel that without some platform issue (require SFMC support), that something small is likely to be the culprit of your error.

Comment: I believe so. I only have access to the Marketing Cloud interface, and the people who provided me with the client ID and secret said it was for my BU. I confirmed that the subdomain for the authentication matched the one they sent me, and the authentication request has always been successful. I've tried a SOAP request using the same token to get a SubscriberKey and it returned a valid response.

Comment: have you tried a retrieve or execute to the Triggered Send Object in SOAP to verify if it is the endpoint or not?

Comment: in your token call you can pass accountid, have you tried putting your BU MID in it

Comment: @Gortonington Ok, I tried to execute the TS via SOAP and I got 'OK' as response, but I haven't received any email and in the Triggered Sends screen I see 0 completed, 0 queued and 0 errored.

Comment: @EazyE That was it! I added the "account_id" parameter to the token request and then used it in the messageDefinitionSends request. I'll add as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per EazyE's comment, I needed to add the parameter `account_id` to the token request, using as value the MID of my Business Unit. Then, I used the token in the `messageDefinitionSends/send` method and the response returned was `Queued` and I checked that the TSD had a message in queue.